# Converting SQL query into Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been trying with no success to translate the following SQL query into ActiveRecord one:

```
SELECT invited.id
FROM (
    SELECT users.id 
    FROM users 
    WHERE users.invited_by_id IS NOT NULL 
) AS invited
JOIN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM users 
    WHERE users.id NOT IN ( 
        SELECT user_id 
        FROM report_logs
    ) 
) AS no_report ON invited.id = no_report.id;
```

I've been using the following command but it doesn't return the same results as the SQL version.

```
@users = User.includes(:report_logs)
         .on(report_logs: { user_id: nil })
         .where("invited_by_id IS NOT NULL")
```

The requirement for the query is to *Find all the users who have been invited by another user and do not possess a report linked to its id*.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be handled by active record scopes. Lets break this down a tad

first, we need a scope to find users that are invited. This can be solved by this scope `User.where.not(invited_by_id: nil)`.

The second scope we need can be constructed again with a scope.  This can be solved by `User.left_outer_joins(:report_logs).where( report_logs: { id: nil } )`

Now we can save these as named scopes in our model for convenient use.

```
class User
  has_many :report_logs
  scope :invited, -> { where.not(invited_by_id: nil) }
  scope :without_report_logs, -> { left_outer_joins(:report_logs).where( report_logs: { id: nil } ) }
end

User.invited.without_report_logs
```